# How Can I Make Popup Blog Content in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, popup, modalpopup

I want to display my reference works on index. I limited the words. My aim is this: User who wants to learn detail information about post, will click the post thumbnail and the rest of content will open with popup.

I used w3css modal to make it. My javascript codes are:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

But only the first post seems like that. The others have no reaction.

Thanks.

[I want to make all thumbnails like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bB2xh.png)

I made some revision about that. I used fancybox 2 and change my code with this

```
<a href="#inline1" rel="gallery" class="fancybox"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'aligncenter')); ?></a>

<div id="inline1" style="width:400px;display: none;">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'aligncenter')); ?><?php the_content(); ?>

</div>
```

Now all the thumbnails open with fancybox but this time the other thumbnails' contents are same with the first post.

Comment: You would need to copy that code and create an modal element in HTML for every image. It doesn't sound about right, I would look into a modal plugin or something.

Comment: i made some revision about that. Now all the thumbnails open with fancybox but this time the other thumbnails' contents are same with the first post. Could you find anything else? @yuriy636

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why fancybox contents are the same in Wordpress?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38871689/why-fancybox-contents-are-the-same-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think create a modal element in every container is a right way to go.

Instead, I will suggest you make only one modal element, and change the content of

that modal when any image got clicked.

thus, here is a demo that I just made

[JSbin](http://jsbin.com/burosonofe/edit?html,css,output)

The step will be

1. find out all container elems
2. bind those elems with `click` event
3. when user click one elem, extract the text and image src of that elem
4. inject into modal-body
5. removve `hide` class

Comment: i made some revision about that. Now all the thumbnails open with fancybox but this time the other thumbnails' contents are same with the first post. Could we apply your way to fancybox? @hiEven

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to have modals mixed in. You have to be a little picky about event handlers and which one to close, but it's not too bad.

```js
var sites = document.querySelectorAll('.site');
var closes = document.querySelectorAll('.close');
var ix;

for (ix = 0; ix < sites.length; ix++) {
  sites.item(ix).addEventListener('click', showModal);
}

for (ix = 0; ix < closes.length; ix++) {
  closes.item(ix).addEventListener('click', closeModal);
}

function showModal(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  this.querySelector('.modal').style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  try {
    getParent(this, 'modal').style.display = "none";
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn('Failed to find my daddy.');
  }
}

function getParent(el, cls) {
  while (el.parentElement) {
    el = el.parentElement;
    if (el.classList.contains(cls)) return el;
  }
  return null;
}
```

```css
.site {
  display: inline-block;
}
.thumbnail {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 50%;
}
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="site">
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">×</span> First Item
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="site">
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">×</span> Second Item
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Will but now there is no reaction when i click the thumbnails.

Comment: You probably need to modify the script a little bit. I made up a div with the class "site" that gets the click handler placed on it. I think you need to add the handlers to divs with the "refotto" class. Example I provided is a simplification of your site, not an exact cut-and-paste job.